# Renaming a Full Text Catalog in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, full-text-catalog

Is there anyway to rename a full text catalog in SQL Server 2008?

There is seemingly no option to do this in SSMS but I am wondering if there is a SQL command to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot rename a full text catalog, you can only drop and recreate it, check out this link for a script you can easily modify to to do this...

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2391904